# Modal en php para mostrar un msj

Tags: php

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    }

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if ($pass==$row['clave']) {

$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;



    header('Location: index2.php');
} else {

    "<div id='mostrarmodal' tabindex='-1' aria-labelledby='basicModal'>
            <div class='modal-dialog'>
                <div >
                    <div class='modal-header'>
                        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times</button>
                        <center><h3>DATOS GUARDADOS CORRECTAMENTE</h3></center>
                        </div>
                        <div class='modal-body'>
                            <center><a class='btn btn-primary' href='index.php'>ACEPTAR</a></center>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='modal-footer'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";
}

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    ?>
```

No sé si este correcta la sintaxis para poner un modal dentro de código php, ayuda.

Comment: No veo el echo después del else, para cargar poner el codigo del modal.

Comment: Ya lo agregué, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer te falta imprimir el codigo html, te falta poner echo, tambien deberias incluir la llamada javascript a ese modal, supongo que si es bootstrap usarias $('#mostrarmodal').modal();

} else {

```
echo "<div id='mostrarmodal' tabindex='-1' aria-labelledby='basicModal'>
        <div class='modal-dialog'>
            <div >
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times</button>
                    <center><h3>DATOS GUARDADOS CORRECTAMENTE</h3></center>
                    </div>
                    <div class='modal-body'>
                        <center><a class='btn btn-primary' href='index.php'>ACEPTAR</a></center>   
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-footer'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
```

}

Comment: Que tal amigo, donde pondria eso que me comentaste?

Comment: Si quieres que muestre al cargar la pagina seria en un script de javascript  <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){ $('#mostrarmodal').modal(); });</script>